Automated action for report filtering in odoo V17.4
I need to perform an automated action in odoo V 17.4 (ONLINE) to obtain a custom view of a production order report, I tried to place this code but it is not working and now the original report fails
# Obtener todas las órdenes de producción con estado 'confirmed' o 'in_progress'
production_orders = env['mrp.production'].search([
    ('state', 'in', ['confirmed', 'in_progress'])
])

# Crear un diccionario para almacenar solo 2 líneas por tipo de producto
filtered_orders = {}
for order in production_orders:
    product_id = order.product_id.id
    if product_id not in filtered_orders:
        filtered_orders[product_id] = []
    if len(filtered_orders[product_id]) < 2:
        filtered_orders[product_id].append(order)

# Crear una lista con los IDs de las órdenes filtradas
result_ids = [order.id for orders in filtered_orders.values() for order in orders]

# Guardar el resultado para mostrar en la vista
return = {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'name': 'Órdenes Filtradas',
    'res_model': 'mrp.production',
    'view_mode': 'tree',
    'domain': [('id', 'in', result_ids)],
}

When I try to save it, it gives me the error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax at line 19
return = {"
I need to filter my production orders by status = "Confirmed" and "in progress", with the condition that only 2 lines are seen in the report by product type

There shouldn't be an = sign after the return keyword.

The error persists after this change

In automated, server and cron python code actions you have to set the variable  action as result. This action will then be "opened".
action = {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'name': 'Órdenes Filtradas',
    'res_model': 'mrp.production',
    'view_mode': 'tree',
    'domain': [('id', 'in', result_ids)],
}

No return needed.

Another idea to solve this is to generate a counter within the order list and with the help of automation only 2 lines are visible for the same type of product, this is my counter but it does not work: def _compute_order_count(self):     for record in self:         record.x_studio_only2 = len(self.env['mrp.production'].search([('product_id', '=', record.product_id.id)]))
